# The success callback of querySP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, csom

I have a SharePoint 2013 hosted app and use CSOM queries to create multiple list items. My question is related to the parameters of the callback method. After executing my query using `clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);` I want to retrieve the ID's of the newly created items without additional queries. I am assuming they are already in the `args` parameter of `onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)` function. So can someone give me a simple example of extracting the ID's of the created items from inside the `onQuerySucceeded` function please?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is the core of my code:

```
    function createListItems(selectedPMs, Username) {
        var itemArray = [];

        var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
        var appUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

        var oWebsite;
        var oList;
        var numItems = selectedPMs.length; 

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(appUrl);
        var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostUrl);

        oWebsite = appContextSite.get_web();
        oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");

        for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            // getItem is my own function, currentDataSet is a global array etc.
            var orgData = getItem(currentDataSet, selectedPMs[i], "JobID");

            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

            oListItem.set_item('CustomerID', Number(orgData.CustomerID));
            oListItem.set_item('CustlocID', Number(orgData.CustomerLocationID));
            oListItem.set_item('Description', orgData.Description);
            oListItem.set_item('EnteredBy', Username);
            oListItem.update();
            itemArray[i] = oListItem;
            clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
        }

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        // Here I want to be able to retrieve and use the 
        // ID's of the newly created items after extracting them from args
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' +   args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a bit more code. The code which you are creating item.

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the array through as an object within the callback context.

See amendments to your script below:

```
        ...
        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
    }

    var o = {"itemArray": itemArray};

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(o, onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(o, onQueryFailed)
    );

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        for(var i = 0; i < o.itemArray.length; i++) {
            var itemId = o.itemArray.get_id():
            // Do your subsequent calls
        }
    }

    ...
```

Note this is untested as I'm not able to get onto SharePoint to try it, but passing the object through often solves similar problems for me.

Comment: Thanks ChrisOi, I will test it tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: Hi again ChrisOi. I actually found a very easy solution to this. All you need is to use itemArray[0].get_id(); inside the onQuerySucceeded function, and it doesn't require creating delegates either.

Comment: Indeed that is a simple solution if the scope of itemArray is greater than just the function and you don't mind keeping that sizable array in memory. If you are not calling this multiple times this will work just fine. In other more complex scenarios you may need to use the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating item as below

```
var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreationInfo);
```

Now `onQuerySucceeded` you can retrieve id using

```
listItem.get_id()
```

**Update**

If you want to get id of each item, then you need to do this differently

```
function createListItems(selectedPMs, Username) {
    var itemArray = [];
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var appUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;
    var numItems = selectedPMs.length; 
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(appUrl);
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostUrl);
    oWebsite = appContextSite.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
    for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        // getItem is my own function, currentDataSet is a global array etc.
        var orgData = getItem(currentDataSet, selectedPMs[i], "JobID");
        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('CustomerID', Number(orgData.CustomerID));
        oListItem.set_item('CustlocID', Number(orgData.CustomerLocationID));
        oListItem.set_item('Description', orgData.Description);
        oListItem.set_item('EnteredBy', Username);
        oListItem.update();
        itemArray[i] = oListItem;
        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }       

    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
        alert("Item created - " + oListItem.get_id());
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' +   args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for the suggestion. The way you are suggesting it creates one item with one call to the server. In my case I have anywhere 10 to 50 items which creates 10 to 50 calls to the server, and I have actually more calls inside the onQuerySucceeded function, which results in hundreds of calls. Is there a way to do a batch process and get a collection of the created items back in one call? That's why I am asking if args parameter could possibly be used.

Comment: You can use browser dev tool and check what values you are receiving back in args object.

Comment: I really don't need to use browser dev tool, I am using Visual Studio and I can see what I am getting back in the args variable which doesn't help at all.